# error:'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, function, built-in, iterable, traceback

In some other tutorial the following  python code for finding words from a json file which worked for them. but, not for me.
would you please help me to get rid of this error.

```
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches

data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def translate(word):
    word = word.lower
    if word in data:
        return data[word]
    elif len(get_close_matches(word, data.keys())) > 0:
        yn=input ("did you mean %s instead? Enter Y if yes and N if no" % get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0])
        if yn == "Y":
            return data[get_close_matches(word, data.keys())[0]]
        elif yn == "N":
            return("the word doesn't exist")
        else:
            print("we don't understand your entry")
    else:
        return("the word does't exist please crosscheck it")

word = input("enter a word: ")

output = translate(word)

if type(output) == list:
    for item in output:
        print(item)
else:
    print(output)
```

This is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pracjson.py", line 23, in <module>

    output = translate(word)
  File "pracjson.py", line 10, in translate
    elif len(get_close_matches(word, data.keys())) > 0:
  File "C:\Users\Vishnu's World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\difflib.py", line 723, in get_close_matches
    s.set_seq2(word)
  File "C:\Users\Vishnu's World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\difflib.py", line 279, in set_seq2
    self.__chain_b()
  File "C:\Users\Vishnu's World\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\difflib.py", line 311, in __chain_b
    for i, elt in enumerate(b):
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in this line:

```
word = word.lower
```

.lower is a method, so it should be:

```
word = word.lower()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `get_close_matches`. But according to the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html, it seems like it needs a list (iterable object).

`data.keys()` returns a dictionary. Try converting that to a list first.

```
    elif len(get_close_matches(word, list(data.keys()))) > 0:
```